# How to read system.webserver configuration section?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, configurationsection

Is there any 'nice' way to read  configuration section group of IIS7 by using WebConfigurationManager o anything?
I tried to read the authorization section but WebConfigurationManager.GetSection() returns an 'IgnoredSection' instance. 
This is what my code looks like...

```
authSection = WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.webServer/security/authorization", HttpContext.Current.Request.Path)
```

Answer (score 9):

```
Configuration webConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath); 
ConfigurationSection cs = webConfig.GetSection("system.webServer");
if (cs != null)
{
    XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(cs.SectionInformation.GetRawXml()));
    ...
}
```

Comment: how to read customheaders values? 

My web.config is as below                                 


<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
        <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>

Comment: @ABB Have a look at this answer for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14249616/657749